# How do i check hadoop server name?

Tags: hadoop

when I try to import data to excel from hdfs, it asks to enter the name of hadoop server, so I am confused what to type there, kindly help me on the same..[image]

Answer (score 0):

Give the name of your Namenode and try once.

Answer (score 0):

You should enter the name of your name node here.

For e.g. in `hdfs-site.xml`, there is a property `dfs.namenode.http-address`, check the value of this property. You need to set this to the name of the server mentioned in this property.

For me, it is set to:

```
<property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.http-address</name>
    <value>mballur.myorg.com:50070</value>
    <description>The address and the base port where the dfs namenode
      web ui will listen on. If the port is 0 then the server will
      start on a free port.</description>
    <final>true</final>
</property>
```

So, if you take my example, you need to set this to `mballur.myorg.com`.

You can also get the name of the NameNode, by running `hadoop fsck` command.

For e.g. when I run the following command:

```
CMD PROMPT>hadoop fsck /tmp/
```

I get the following output:

```
Connecting to namenode via http://mballur.myorg.com:50070/fsck?ugi=mballur&path=%2Ftmp
FSCK started by mballur (auth:SIMPLE) from /192.168.56.1 for path /tmp at Wed Jan 06 18:29:57 IST 2016
```

You can see the first line, highlighted portion is the name of the Name Node:

Connecting to namenode via http://**mballur.myorg.com**:50070/fsck?ugi=mballur&path=%2Ftmp

Also, check this tutorial in Youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_eyE7Qcj0_A

Comment: I am using already configured hadoop which has given by my friend, so here the content of hdfs-site.xml...

    <configuration>
    <property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>1</value>
    </property>
    <property>
    <name>dfs.block.size</name>
    <value>67108864</value>
    </property>
    </configuration> 

so how to get the name of the namenode?

Comment: Do you have access to this Hadoop cluster? You can check the name of the NameNode, by running `hadoop fsck /` command.

Comment: ERROR security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:root cause:java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

Comment: I am getting the above error when I try with hadoop fsck / command, yes I have the access to hadoop cluster

Comment: Can you try `hadoop fsck /tmp/` or `hadoop fsck /usr/`. You don't have access to root

Comment: when I run hadoop fsck / command I got connecting to namenode via http://localhost:50070
fsck started by hadoop (auth:SIMPLE) from /127.0.0.1 for path

Comment: when I run hadoop fsck / command I got                                                 connecting to namenode via http://localhost:50070
fsck started by hadoop (auth:SIMPLE) from /127.0.0.1                            when I give localhost:50070 in power query of excel to connect to hadoop it is giving error as                                                   Details: "HDFS cannot connect to server '127.0.0.1'. Unable to connect to the remote server. so kindly let me know what to do